# How to login to site and send data

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to send information to open a website, keepa.com, then log in with my username and password, then open the search tab and send a product code in order to get back data about that product.

My python code to open the website and to send the product code to the site works, but I can't work out the code for a couple key steps: to first log in to the site and to open the "search" tab where I send the product code.

Appreciate any guidance. Thanks.

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(('https://keepa.com/#!'))
#need code here to log in#
#need code here to open search tab#    
asin = '1889814083'
isbn = browser.find_element_by_id('menuSearch')
isbn = browser.find_element_by_id('searchInput')
isbn.send_keys(asin)
isbn.submit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an explicit wait:

> *An implicit wait directs the WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time (as mentioned in the command) when trying to locate an element that is not visible immediately. The default value of time that can be set using Implicit wait is zero. Its unit is in seconds. Implicit wait remains associated with the web element until it gets destroyed.*

and when you find the `menuSearch` id, click on it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(('https://keepa.com/#!'))
#need code here to log in#
#need code here to open search tab#    
asin = '1889814083'
browser.implicitly_wait(2)
isbn = browser.find_element_by_id('menuSearch').click()
isbn = browser.find_element_by_id('searchInput')
isbn.send_keys(asin)
isbn.submit()
```